# Mockito is verifying the wrong method

Tags: android, mockito, android-espresso, android-testing

I'm following MVP architecture in my app using the [Nucleus](https://github.com/konmik/nucleus) library, and am trying to mock the Presenter for my Fragment. The mock and its overridden invocations work perfectly fine, but my `verify` calls are strange. First, here's my test:

```
private User mUser;
private ProfilePresenter mPresenterMock;

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    mUser = TestUtils.generateTestUser();
    mPresenterMock = mock(ProfilePresenter.class);

    ProfileFragment fragment = ProfileFragment.newInstance();
    fragment.setPresenterFactory(() -> mPresenterMock);
    setFragment(fragment);
}

@Test
public void testInitialValues() {
    doAnswer(invocation -> {
        getFragment().onUserLoaded(mUser);
        return null;
    }).when(mPresenterMock).loadUser(anyBoolean());

    startFragment();
    verify(mPresenterMock).loadUser(eq(false));
    onView(withId(R.id.empty)).check(matches(not(withEffectiveVisibility(VISIBLE))));
    assertEquals(mUser.getFullName(), getFragment().mToolbar.getTitle());
    assertEquals(1, getFragment().mVideosRecyclerView.getChildCount());
}
```

I get a test failure on the `verify` line:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
profilePresenter.start(false);
Actual invocation has different arguments:
profilePresenter.start(1);
```

What it appears to be doing is verifying a method *inside* the mocked class, which shouldn't be the case if it's a mocked object. This is the `loadUser` method inside my Presenter which invokes `start`:

```
void loadUser(boolean fresh) {
    start(fresh ? USER_FRESH : USER_CACHED);
}
```

Where `start` takes an integer parameter.

I've debugged the test and have verified that the Fragment is indeed using the mocked Presenter as expected. I also put a breakpoint inside my `doAnswer` to verify it is being triggered correctly, and it is.

So what could cause Mockito to verify a method invocation inside of the method I'm trying to `verify` in the mocked class? I'm using version 1.10.19.

Comment: I wonder if this is weird behaviour of mockito is because your `when` statement is composed incorrectly... Generally you write the stub inside the parenthesis of `when()` otherwise it will not be stubbed properly and the real method will be called.

Comment: @Be_Negative That's the correct format. You can't use an `OngoingStubbing` if you're stubbing a void method. [JavaDoc](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/stubbing/Stubber.html#when(T))